# Update more than one document in a loop

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, pouchdb, upsert

Background:

I use [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) (indexedDB) for an offline NW.js App and I'm new to no-sql. I also use the PouchDB plugin [Upsert](https://github.com/pouchdb/upsert), this basiclly does an db.get() and db.put() in the background.

Problem:
I dynamically create *n* documents and in another function i want to update them all with the *upsert* function in a loop, but i have to *return* the document that I want to update. So the loop stops at the first run(logically, just normal behavior).
Is there a way to update *n* documents with one function in a loop?

Here's my code example:

```
var temp = $('#number_discuss_points').val();

for (i = 1; i < temp; i++) {
    var v1= $('#discusspoint_heading' + i).val();
    var v2= $('#discusspoint_subheading' + i).val();
    var v3= $('#point_number' + i).val();
    var v4= $('#dpoint_deadline' + i).val();
    var v5= $('#responsible_person' + i).val();
    var v6= $('#dp_text' + i).val();  

    db.upsert(id_body + i, function (sheet) {
        sheet._id = id_body + i;
        sheet.discusspoint_heading = v1;
        sheet.discusspoint_subheading = v2;
        sheet.point_number = v3;
        sheet.dpoint_deadline = v4;
        sheet.responsible_person = v5;
        sheet.dp_text = v6;

        return sheet; //Logically, the functions stops here and return everthing with 1

    }).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Nolan Lawson will be along shortly with a much better answer than me, but here goes anyway... in your loop you can add each returned promise from db.upsert into an array. After the loop, you can use Promise.all to process all the promises like this:

```
var temp = $('#number_discuss_points').val();

var promise_list = [];

for (i = 1; i < temp; i++) {
    var v1= $('#discusspoint_heading' + i).val();
    var v2= $('#discusspoint_subheading' + i).val();
    var v3= $('#point_number' + i).val();
    var v4= $('#dpoint_deadline' + i).val();
    var v5= $('#responsible_person' + i).val();
    var v6= $('#dp_text' + i).val();  

    promise_list.push(db.upsert(id_body + i, function (sheet) {
        sheet._id = id_body + i;
        sheet.discusspoint_heading = v1;
        sheet.discusspoint_subheading = v2;
        sheet.point_number = v3;
        sheet.dpoint_deadline = v4;
        sheet.responsible_person = v5;
        sheet.dp_text = v6;

        return sheet; //Logically, the functions stops here and return everthing with 1
    }));
}

Promise.all(promise_list).then(function (result_list) {
    for(var result in result_list) {
        console.log(result);
    }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Nolan covers this very well in his post "[We have a problem with promises](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html)".

Comment: Thank you! I have not completely done it yet, but this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Alternatively, you could generate the docs in the 'for loop' and use a single `db.bulkdocs()` operation, which would be more efficient. However, this assumes that you already have the existing doc `_rev` data to pass along or the new docs don't already exist. However, the `db.upsert()` solution above is more robust as it takes care of this for us.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, in my opinion it is not deterministic. In my case when the diffFunc in upsert enter the external loop is ended so I get only the last values for v1...v6. Is it possible to determine in upsert diffFunc the id I was looking for? Do you have other ideas?

Comment: I solved the problem in the previous comment by calculating v1...v6 inside upsert diffFunc using another counter initialized to 0 before for loop.

Answer (score 1):

First create an array of docs inside a for loop:

```
docArray=[]

for(i=1;i<10;i++){
    /* Create doc */
    doc={}
    doc._id=i
    doc.whatever='The Power of '+ i
    /* Push doc to array */
    docArray.push(doc)
}
```

Now, reduce the `docArray` to a chained promise:

```
docArray.reduce((seq,doc)=>{
    return seq.then(()=>{
        /*Chain "db.pusert" promise to seq*/
        return db.upsert(doc._id,function(docOLD){return doc})
    });
},Promise.resolve()/* Initial value of seq */)
.then(res=>{console.log('All "db.upserts" resolved')})
.catch(err=>{throw new Error(err)})
```